# How to idetify the phonetic alphabets in MS SQL database tables

Tags: sql-server, database, phonetics

We have inserted more than 100000 records through Import flat file functionality in sql server management studio. It was inserted successfully.
But some of column values contained characters like é and ö .
It got converted into  while storing in sql column for all above characters like(ö,é).

Moreover the below SQL statements is not giving any results.

```
select * from Temp where column1 like '%%'
```

The data with these characters in the tables are being displayed with a symbol(question mark in a diamond).

Please help as to how can I insert the data keeping the phoentic symobols intact.

Comment: Can you give a few example of data of the import file and the data you have now on MS SQL?

Comment: Also please give the definition of the table you inserted into.

Comment: Hi @FrancescoMantovani. Möller in the file is M�ller in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data contains some characters like é and ö. But when you see in the database, it's stored "?" instead of that, right?

I think, your database does not support all characters. I would recommend to change it to something like this:

```
character set: utf8
collation: utf8_general_ci
```

Hope to help, my friend :))

Answer (score 0):

character set: utf8
collation: utf8_general_ci

Answer (score -1):

```html
SELECT 
 * 
FROM TEMP 
WHERE SOUNDEX(COLUMN1) LIKE SOUNDEX('A')
```

**strong text**